# How to set the environmental variable for SDK on MAC machine

Tags: android, macos, environment-variables, system, command-prompt

In MAC machine, I setup the environmental variables for *ANDROID SDK*

Opened the terminal & entered the following commands

```
 export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx export
 PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

In the terminal I verified the path by typing **export**

[image: PATH]

In the above image, the **PATH** is appended with some other values whether those appended value is the issue or not?

Then, When I try to run it from *eclipse*, an error message is displayed like 
**Console Error**

> A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find
>   adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android
>   SDK root directory path.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 350 milliseconds

Suggestions and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set those environmental as *System-wide environmental variables*. and it works now.

Previously I didn't set the *environmental variable(ANDROID_HOME) as system-wide variable*, that is the reason why the ANDROID_HOME variable is invisible in Eclipse Environment settings.

To set the ANDROID_HOME as System-wide environmental variable, I have used the following commands in terminal and some settings in Eclipse.

**Terminal:**

```
Run sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf
Add setenv ANDROID_HOME /Users/selvakumar/Documents/android-sdk-macosx
Then either restart or run launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf; sudo launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf
```

**Eclipse:**

Then the variable becomes visible in the **Eclipse--> Run Configurations--> Environment -->Select-->ANDROID_HOME** then I checked the ANDROID_HOME variable and click apply. Run the code with your new Run configuration settings. That made my code to work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the path in `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/Users/vinay.maneti/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/vinay.maneti/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
```

Comment: Can you please explain the source line

Answer (score 0):

You have to add them to **.bash_profile** and **.bashrc**

.bash_profile is the file which will be called whenever you open terminal and .bashrc will be called to load environment variables outside of terminal. So create two files

1. .bash_profile in your HOME directory and store all the environment variables there
2. .bashrc - write a line to execute .bash_profile

Eg:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
echo '. .bash_profile' > ~/.bashrc
```

Edit :
Setting the path directly in .bash_profile

Fill the path using vim editor.

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx 
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
:wq
```

Then execute the .bash_profile once

```
. .bash_profile
```

Comment: It didnt works. I tried with the following
echo 'export PATH=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
echo '. .bash_profile' > ~/.bashrc

Comment: Check the edit. Set the path directly in .bash_profile in your home directory and execute it once

Comment: I have used the VIM editor and I did the above changes. It get updated too. But when I run it in eclipse I get the same error. (Updated in my question)

Comment: I have edited the question can you give your feedback

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your eclipse error. Also can you post the screenshot of Android preferences in your eclipse

Comment: Unable to upload more images here. Kindly [Click here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/could-not-find-adb-please-set-the-android-home-environment-variable-with-the-android-sdk-root-directory-path/4875?u=ashokkumarg) for more details.

Comment: Your SDK location in preferences does not match with your path. Change it to `/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/sdk` in your Eclipse preferences and try again

Comment: Actually now I moved the sdk set up into 
/Users/selvakumar/Documents/android-sdk-macosx. Also I changed the enviromental set up paths too. Sorry that screen shot was taken before. I will correct it. Now the Android preferences & Environmental are in the same path as I mentioned in this comment.